# Retrieving Dictionary from Datatable

Tags: c#

Have this dictionay retrieving values from DataTable:

```
Dictionary<string,string> meta= ds.Tables[1].Select("key<>'format'").AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(k=>k.Field<string>(0),v=>v.Field<string>(1));
```

How would I apply StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as Mehrdad Afshari suggested ?

Comment: Is it possible to know what the suggestion is?

Comment: I think the suggestion was to provide StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase to the constructor of a dictionary to enable case-insensitive key lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in another constructor:

```
var meta = new Dictionary<string,string>(ds.Tables[1]
                                           .Select("key<>'format'")
                                           .AsEnumerable()
                                           .ToDictionary(k=>k.Field<string>(0),
                                                         v=>v.Field<string>(1)),
                                         StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```